# Identification: A short story about a character in a video game that is trying to be friends with his mother

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this story, the main character is a video game character. He (or she, I can't remember) travels around with a friend and is killing aliens. He is trying to defeat the aliens in order to level up and gain enough charisma so that he can talk to his mother again.

Apparently he became enemies with his mother at some point in time in the past, and has regretted it, but is not presented dialog options that allow him to talk to her and apologize to her.

A few interesting points that I remember are:

- There was a time when the protagonist tried to talk to an alien but couldn't say anything useful.
- The friend had a cut-scene where he saved the protagonist, and was embarrassed by it.
- The protagonist is amused that spiders that he fought as a kid dropped items and money - he wondered about where and how they would hold the items, or why they had them.
- The alien invasion is called "endgame materiel" by the protagonist (or the friend), and apparently the drops are much better then than they would get before.
- They don't seem to know they are in a video game, but they are definitely aware of the rules of the game, and talk at times in a fourth wall breaking manner.

I believe that I read this online, and not more than three years ago. I do not know when it was written.